# Elegant resample for groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For a given pandas data frame called `full_df` which looks like

```
  index   id   timestamp    data  
 ------- ---- ------------ ------ 
      1    1   2017-01-01   10.0  
      2    1   2017-02-01   11.0  
      3    1   2017-04-01   13.0  
      4    2   2017-02-01    1.0  
      5    2   2017-03-01    2.0  
      6    2   2017-05-01    9.0
```

The start and end dates (and the time delta between start and end) are varying.

But I need a id wise resampled version (added rows marked with `*`)

```
  index   id   timestamp    data       
 ------- ---- ------------ ------ ---- 
      1    1   2017-01-01   10.0       
      2    1   2017-02-01   11.0       
      3    1   2017-03-01    NaN   *   
      4    1   2017-04-01   13.0       
      5    2   2017-02-01    1.0       
      6    2   2017-03-01    2.0       
      7    2   2017-04-01    NaN   *   
      8    2   2017-05-01    9.0
```

Because the dataset is very large I was wondering if there is more efficient way of doing so than

1. Do `full_df.groupby('id')`
2. Do for each group `df`

   ```
   df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp'])
   all_days = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='MS')
   df = df.reindex(all_days)
   ```
3. Combine all groups again with a new index

That's time consuming and not very elegant. Any ideas?

Comment: The start end end dates are varying for each `id`.

Comment: you  had `2017-05-01` in your starting sample for id 2 though

Comment: Oh I am sorry, copy paste error. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: one small note, `all` is also a built-in. To avoid strange troubles further on, you might want to pick a different name for the DataFrame

Comment: I renamed `all` into `full_df`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `resample`

```
In [1175]: (df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id').resample('MS').asfreq()
              .drop(['id', 'index'], 1).reset_index())
Out[1175]:
   id  timestamp  data
0   1 2017-01-01  10.0
1   1 2017-02-01  11.0
2   1 2017-03-01   NaN
3   1 2017-04-01  13.0
4   2 2017-02-01   1.0
5   2 2017-03-01   2.0
6   2 2017-04-01   NaN
7   2 2017-05-01   9.0
```

Details

```
In [1176]: df
Out[1176]:
   index  id  timestamp  data
0      1   1 2017-01-01  10.0
1      2   1 2017-02-01  11.0
2      3   1 2017-04-01  13.0
3      4   2 2017-02-01   1.0
4      5   2 2017-03-01   2.0
5      6   2 2017-05-01   9.0

In [1177]: df.dtypes
Out[1177]:
index                 int64
id                    int64
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
data                float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: note that a groupby with id and a Grouper on freq would be efficient on a large amount of groups

Comment: Just to be clear, "df" here is what the OP calls "all"?  I think in the OP here is an implicit `for df in all`, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit to add:** this way does the min/max of dates for `full_df`, not `df`.  If there wide variation in start/end dates between IDs this will unfortunately inflate the dataframe and @JohnGalt method is better.  Nevertheless I'll leave this here as an alternate approach as it ought to be faster than groupby/resample for cases where it is appropriate.

---

I think the most efficient approach is likely going to be with stack/unstack or melt/pivot.

You could do something like this, for example:

```
full_df.set_index(['timestamp','id']).unstack('id').stack('id',dropna=False)

               index  data
timestamp  id             
2017-01-01 1     1.0  10.0
           2     NaN   NaN
2017-02-01 1     2.0  11.0
           2     4.0   1.0
2017-03-01 1     NaN   NaN
           2     5.0   2.0
2017-04-01 1     3.0  13.0
           2     NaN   NaN
2017-05-01 1     NaN   NaN
           2     6.0   9.0
```

Just add `reset_index().set_index('id')` if you want it to display more like how you have it above.  Note in particular the use of `dropna=False` with stack which preserves the NaN placeholders.  Without that, the stack/unstack method just leaves you back where you started.

This method automatically includes the min & max dates, and all dates present for at least one timestamp.  If there are interior timestamps missing for everyone, then you need to add a `resample` like this:

```
full_df.set_index(['timestamp','id']).unstack('id')\
   .resample('MS').mean()\
   .stack('id',dropna=False)
```

Comment: But than we got very large data frames in terms of size right? Especially when the dates are not close to each other (e.g.1978 and 2017, 5 months each).

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood.  You want the min/max date to be for "df", not "all"?  Sorry, I'll add a comment to my answer to clarify that.