# Groupby and resample using forward and backward fill in window in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, pandas-resample

I want to resample data column using forward fill `ffill` and backward fill `bfill` at the frequency of `1min` while grouping `df` by `id` column.

`df`:

```
          id   timestamp                data  

      1    1   2017-01-02 13:14:53.040  10.0
      2    1   2017-01-02 16:04:43.240  11.0  
                           ...
      4    2   2017-01-02 15:22:06.540   1.0  
      5    2   2017-01-03 13:55:34.240   2.0  
                           ...
```

I used:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id', sort=True)['data'].resample('1min').ffill().bfill())
```

How can I add an additional condition, by resampling within the window of past 10 days from now? So the last `timestamp` reading is now and the first `timestamp` reading is **datetime.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("10day")**. The goal is to have the same number of readings for each `id` group.

---

Update:

Tried:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("10day")
end = datetime.datetime.now()

r = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='1h'))

pd.DataFrame(df.reset_index().set_index('timestamp').groupby('id', sort=True).reindex(r)['data'].resample('1h').ffill().bfill())
```

and returned:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reindex'
```

so I'm not supposed to apply `reindex` for `groupby` object, is there a way that I can work around it?

Comment: Filter the entire dataframe for 10day then groupby and resample, them concat back with other portion of the original dataframe older than 10day.

Comment: Hi @ScottBoston thanks for the suggestion, I thought about that but by filtering the dataframe for 10 day doesn't give me the exact "10 day time interval in actual data" as the actual data for each `id` were not recorded at the same time and may have different start time.

Comment: `df[df['timestamp'] >= (pd.Timestamp('now') - pd.Timedelta('10d')).normalize()]`

Comment: @ScottBoston Definition of `pandas.Series.dt.normalize` states `Convert times to midnight.` which I think stretched the boundary timestamp to midnight but it doesn't really matter because the actual start time for different `id` are still gonna be different as long as the start time is not specified for backward fill? I'd like different `id` group to start at the same time after resampling and have the same number of readings eventually. CMIIW thanks

Comment: @nilsinelabore that sounds like a pivot thing. Resample your data for each id, then pivot. Another way is to generate the common time windows, then `merge_asof`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the ideas. Could you please advise a good way to generate common time windows? I'm thinking about using `date_range` with custom function, something like `def w(x):
    r = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start='2017-12-23', end='2017-01-02 23:00:00', freq='1h'))

    return x.reindex(r, method='ffill')` but I'm struggling with indexing terms like `set_index`, `reset_index`,  `reindex` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a data, I can't really test this. So take this as a suggestion/comment put for proper formatting. Since you are looking to resample with `bfill/ffill`, I think `merge_asof` would work:

```
# common time window
r = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start='2017-12-23', end='2017-01-02 23:00:00', freq='1h')) 

# unique id
unique_ids = df['id'].unique()

# new time reference:
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(unique_ids, len(r)),
                       'time': np.tile(r, len(unique_ids)),
                      })

# merge_asof may complain about sorting key, then sort both df by time
# default of merge_asof is `direction='backward'`
# change to `direction='forward'` if you want to *floor* time
out = pd.merge_asof(new_df, df, on='time', by='id')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you know what might have caused all the values returned to be `NaN`?